# Using fromField in Hierarchical Object

Tags: amcharts, amstock

Given the following dataset design

```
[{
  "date": Date,
  "parent": {
    "child": Number
  },
  "volume": Number
}]
```

Is it possible to create a fieldMapping like the following

```
{
  "fromField": "parent.child",
  "toField": "value"
}
```

(Just incase I didn't make it clear, `parent.child` doesn't work. It's just an example syntax for the use case I'm looking for.)

I can't find any mention of this in the documentation and I have attempted guessing different syntax for it to no avail.

I know one work around would be to restructure the data to be a flat design but it would be awesome if we didn't have to do that.

Thank you for your time!
Max

Comment: Nested objects aren't supported. This was also answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39233191/how-to-access-nested-json-data-in-amcharts)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response!